# Flyway Migration error flyway 4 to flyway 9.10.0 Unable to decrease block depth below throwing while script excution

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, oracle, flyway

We're encountering errors when migrating from Flyway version 4 to version 9 in our script. Modifying the script would lead to checksum errors. Is there a solution to prevent this issue? While this problem was addressed in Flyway 6.4.1, it still persists. We're currently using Flyway 9 to support PostgreSQL version 15. Downgrading to multiple versions didn't trigger this error, except in version 5.2, which lacks support for PostgreSQL 15. We need a version that resolves our Flyway issue for PostgreSQL without script errors. Upgrading to Flyway versions 9.15.1 and 9.16 is causing Gson errors, despite having Gson installed.
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE EPCIS_MAINTENANCE_PAK
AS

```
PROCEDURE CAPTURE_SQL
   (P_RUN_FROM             VARCHAR2,
    P_SQL_STMT             VARCHAR2,
    P_RUN_TIME             TIMESTAMP,
    P_ERROR_MSG            VARCHAR2);

PROCEDURE MAINTENANCE_LOG
   (P_TASK_NAME            VARCHAR2,
    P_TASK_STARTED         TIMESTAMP,
    P_TASK_ENDED           TIMESTAMP,
    P_RESULTS              VARCHAR2,
    P_DESCRIPTION          VARCHAR2);

PROCEDURE PARTITION_MANAGEMENT;


END EPCIS_MAINTENANCE_PAK;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY EPCIS_MAINTENANCE_PAK
AS

--
-- PROCEDURE: CAPTURE_SQL
-- THIS PROCEDURE ALLOWS OTHER MAINTENANCE PROCEDURES TO LOG THE FINAL SQL THEY
-- IS TO BE RUN USING DYNAMIC SQL
--

PROCEDURE CAPTURE_SQL
   (P_RUN_FROM             VARCHAR2,
    P_SQL_STMT             VARCHAR2,
    P_RUN_TIME             TIMESTAMP,
    P_ERROR_MSG            VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CAPTURED_SQL
         (RUN_FROM, SQL_STMT, RUN_TIME, ERROR_MSG)
    VALUES
         (P_RUN_FROM, P_SQL_STMT, P_RUN_TIME, P_ERROR_MSG);
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END CAPTURE_SQL;

--
-- PROCEDURE: MAINTENANCE_LOG
-- THIS PROCEDURE SIMPLY ALLOWS OTHER MAINTENANCE JOBS TO LOG THEIR SUCCESS OR
-- FAILURE
--

PROCEDURE MAINTENANCE_LOG
   (P_TASK_NAME            VARCHAR2,
    P_TASK_STARTED         TIMESTAMP,
    P_TASK_ENDED           TIMESTAMP,
    P_RESULTS              VARCHAR2,
    P_DESCRIPTION          VARCHAR2)
IS
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO MAINTENANCE_LOG (TASK_NAME, TASK_STARTED, TASK_ENDED, RESULTS, DESCRIPTION)
   VALUES (P_TASK_NAME, P_TASK_STARTED, P_TASK_ENDED, P_RESULTS, P_DESCRIPTION);
   COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END MAINTENANCE_LOG;

--
-- PROCEDURE: PARTITION_MANAGEMENT
-- THIS PARTITION_MANAGEMENT IS CALLED BY THE NIGHTLY JOB AND IT WILL MAINTAIN
-- THE PARTITION TABLES BY ADDING NEW PARTITIONS (BY SPLITTING THE MAXVALUE
-- PARTITION) SO THAT FUTURE PARTITIONS ARE CREATED AHEAD OF TIME BASED ON
-- SETTINGS IN THE PARTITION_MANAGEMENT TABLE
--
PROCEDURE PARTITION_MANAGEMENT
IS
   V_STARTED      TIMESTAMP := SYSTIMESTAMP;
   V_CNT          NUMBER;
   V_MAX          DATE;
   V_MAXVALPART   VARCHAR2(100);
   V_MAX_REQUIRED DATE;
   V_STMT         VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PARTITION_MANAGEMENT - Begin');
   FOR R IN (SELECT *
               FROM PARTITION_MANAGEMENT
              WHERE PARTITIONED_YN = 'Y') LOOP

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PARTITION_MANAGEMENT.TABLE_NAME: '||R.TABLE_NAME);

      SELECT NVL(MAX(DECODE(INSTR(PARTITION_NAME, 'MAXVALUE'), 0,
                            TO_DATE(RPAD(SUBSTR(PARTITION_NAME,
                                    DECODE(R.PARTITION_SIZE_MDY, 'D', -8
                                                               , 'M', -6)),
                                         8, '01'), 'YYYYMMDD'))),
                 DECODE(R.PARTITION_SIZE_MDY, 'D', TRUNC(SYSDATE),
                                              'M', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'))),
             MAX(DECODE(INSTR(PARTITION_NAME, 'MAXVALUE'), 0, NULL, PARTITION_NAME))
        INTO V_MAX, V_MAXVALPART
        FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
       WHERE TABLE_NAME = R.TABLE_NAME;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('V_MAX: '||TO_CHAR(V_MAX, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('V_MAXVALPART: '||V_MAXVALPART);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PARTITION_SIZE_MDY: '||R.PARTITION_SIZE_MDY);


      IF V_MAXVALPART IS NULL THEN
         EXIT;
      ELSIF R.PARTITION_SIZE_MDY = 'D' THEN
         V_MAX_REQUIRED := TRUNC(SYSDATE) + R.PARTITIONS_TO_PREBUILD;
      ELSIF R.PARTITION_SIZE_MDY = 'M' THEN
         V_MAX_REQUIRED := ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), R.PARTITIONS_TO_PREBUILD);
      END IF;
      --SPLITS
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('V_MAX_REQUIRED: '||TO_CHAR(V_MAX_REQUIRED, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'));
      WHILE V_MAX < V_MAX_REQUIRED LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LOOP for '||TO_CHAR(V_MAX, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'));

         IF R.PARTITION_SIZE_MDY = 'D' THEN
            V_MAX := V_MAX + 1;
            V_STMT := 'ALTER TABLE ' || R.TABLE_NAME ||
                      ' SPLIT PARTITION ' || V_MAXVALPART ||
                      ' AT (TO_DATE(''' || TO_CHAR(V_MAX + 1, 'YYYYMMDD') ||
                      ''' , ''YYYYMMDD'')) INTO (PARTITION P_' || R.PARTITION_NAME_STRING || '_' ||
                      TO_CHAR(V_MAX, 'YYYYMMDD') || ', PARTITION ' || V_MAXVALPART || ')';

            CAPTURE_SQL
               (P_RUN_FROM  => 'PARTITION_MANAGEMENT',
                P_SQL_STMT  => V_STMT,
                P_RUN_TIME  => SYSTIMESTAMP,
                P_ERROR_MSG => 'N/A');

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_STMT;
         ELSIF R.PARTITION_SIZE_MDY = 'M' THEN
            V_MAX := ADD_MONTHS(V_MAX, 1);
            V_STMT := 'ALTER TABLE ' || R.TABLE_NAME ||
                      ' SPLIT PARTITION ' || V_MAXVALPART ||
                      ' AT (TO_DATE(''' || TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(V_MAX, 1), 'YYYYMM') ||
                      ''' , ''YYYYMM'')) INTO (PARTITION P_' || R.PARTITION_NAME_STRING || '_' ||
                      TO_CHAR(V_MAX, 'YYYYMM') || ', PARTITION ' || V_MAXVALPART || ')';

            CAPTURE_SQL
               (P_RUN_FROM  => 'PARTITION_MANAGEMENT',
                P_SQL_STMT  => V_STMT,
                P_RUN_TIME  => SYSTIMESTAMP,
                P_ERROR_MSG => 'N/A');

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_STMT;
            V_CNT := V_CNT + 1;
         END IF;

         UPDATE PARTITION_MANAGEMENT
            SET LAST_DDL = SYSDATE
          WHERE TABLE_NAME = R.TABLE_NAME;
         COMMIT;
      END LOOP;--SPLITS
   END LOOP; --PARTITION_MANAGEMENT

   MAINTENANCE_LOG
      (P_TASK_NAME    => 'PARTITION_MANAGEMENT',
       P_TASK_STARTED => V_STARTED,
       P_TASK_ENDED   => SYSTIMESTAMP,
       P_RESULTS      => 'SUCCESSFUL',
       P_DESCRIPTION  => 'ADDED ' || V_CNT || 'PARTITIONS');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PARTITION_MANAGEMENT - End');

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      MAINTENANCE_LOG
         (P_TASK_NAME    => 'PARTITION_MANAGEMENT',
          P_TASK_STARTED => V_STARTED,
          P_TASK_ENDED   => SYSTIMESTAMP,
          P_RESULTS      => 'FAILED',
          P_DESCRIPTION  => SQLERRM);

END PARTITION_MANAGEMENT;

END EPCIS_MAINTENANCE_PAK;

-- SHOW ERRORS

call EPCIS_MAINTENANCE_PAK.PARTITION_MANAGEMENT();
```

Comment: The text of the question says PostgreSQL, the code looks like Oracle and you have tagged both. Which RDBMS are you using? (and is the code actually relevant to the problem of migrating versions?)

Comment: this is code for orcale and we support postgresql also